# Receiving "Illegal Argument" for encoding contentVersion to base64

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout

I need to send the file attached in the salesforce object by using a rest call but the following line goes in error :

```
String body = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cVersion.VersionData);
```

cVersione is the contentVersion I receive as parameter in a method.

It works in the developer console but not in the apex method. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation for the EncodingUtil class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_base64Encode) points out, the `base64Encode()` method takes a `Blob` as an argument, not a string.

If you have a string and need to base64 encode it, you need to turn it into a Blob first. Something like `EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(myString));`

But you shouldn't need to do any of that here, as the `versionData` of a `ContentVersion` is already base64 encoded. The [ContentVersion documentation is here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) and the relevant part of that is

> ### VersionData
>
> #### Type
>
> base64
>
> #### Properties
>
> Create, Nillable
>
> #### Description
>
> Encoded file data. This field can't be set for links. The maximum file size you can upload via the SOAP API must be less than 50 MB. When a document is uploaded or downloaded via the API, it is converted to base64 and stored in VersionData. This conversion increases the document size by approximately 37%. You must account for the base64 conversion increase so that the file you plan to upload is less than 50 MB.

If it worked in the developer console, then I suspect the `ContentVersion` you were passing into the method had a null `versionData`.